# Complex Analysis Question - Cosine and quadratic combined

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

i was doing some questions in my complex analysis booklet and have came across the following question that i don't seem to be able to get the answer for. Hoping someone on here can help!

So it's the integral is $$\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+4x+5} dx$$

Really would be a lot of help if someone could help me with this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Your integral is the real part of $$\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(z)dz$$ where $$f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+4z+5}$$
2. $f(z)$ vanishes on the upper half plane as $|z|\to\infty$.
3. Use a semicircle contour on the upper half plane centered at the origin.
4. Then apply residue theorem.
5. The only enclosed pole is at $-2+i$, and it is a simple pole.

---

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-2+i}f(z)=\lim_{z\to-2+i}\frac{e^{iz}}{(z-(-2+i))(z-(-2-i))}\cdot(z-(-2+i))$$

Comment: Thanks! I can get the pole to be -2+i and then i know to apply the residue theorem but i'm getting a strange answer when i do that. I get e^(-2i)/(-4+2i)e as the residue. I think i'm just getting a sign mixed up somewhere though...

Comment: @paul See my edited answer.

Comment: @paul If I did math correctly in my brain, your integral should equal to $\frac{\pi}e\cos 2$.

Comment: that's the answer i got so your brain must be correct! Thanks again for the help, i wasn't considering the second pole when factorizing to calculate the residue as its outside the semicircle contour, but it's still needed for when calculating the residue, oops!

Comment: @paul If you think my answer is somewhat useful please kindly accept it.